# Gravitational potential energy

Tags: gravity, energy, energy-conservation, potential-energy

Consider two places next to each other: Place 1, where there is a gravitational field whereas Place 2 - there's no field.

Now if we lifted a box in place 1, it gains potential energy. Then, we move this box horizontally to place 2. What happens to this energy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is very wrong. Gravity is everywhere. Or simply, the box has *mass*. It exerts its very own gravity. If your 1st location has the field, then the 2nd location is also influenced by it unless it is at $\infty$. You can't just **shield** anything from [gravitational field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_field). So, Energy is still conserved when you're moving the box from one place to another...